# Samba - Network transfers from one share to another... local or LAN based?

Tags: server, samba, lan

I have Samba running on my server, which is Ubuntu Server 12.04. I have Ubuntu 12.04 desktop edition on my desktop. If I connect to a share on my server and I want to move files from one directory to another hosted by Samba, am I inadvertently caching the files on my desktop before they're moving to the other directory? Based on the speed I'm getting it feels like I'm transferring a file over the LAN. In the efforts of speed, I suppose if I want to move files locally without any LAN-oriented transfer interaction with my desktop, I'd be better off SSH'ing in and simply mv'ing everything I want. Eh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> am I inadvertently caching the files on my desktop before they're
>   moving to the other directory?

Yes, you are.

> I suppose if I want to move files locally without any LAN-oriented
>   transfer interaction with my desktop, I'd be better off SSH'ing in and
>   simply mv'ing everything I want. Eh?

That is precisely how to move things like this.